# Псевдокласс before: - наложение

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, sass

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что при изменении высоты, сползает сильно наложение.
Не знаю как решить. Предполагаю, что при помощи JS.
[image: Проблема]

```css
/*Часть стилей, отвечающая за наложение цвета на картинку*/

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("../img/bg/1.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #14134b;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-logo-wrap">
      <img src="./img/icon/icon-top.png" alt="" srcset="">
      <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <form action="" id="form-sign-up">
    <label for="">Username</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label for="">Password</label>
    <input type="password">
    <button>Sign In</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Тут нет компилятора css-препроцессоров. Создайте воспроизводимую проблему в сниппете - это сильно увеличит ваши шансы на получение ответа.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что у `body` стоит высота в абсолютных еденицах `vh`.

Answer (score 0):

Решается вопрос min-height: 100vh;